# Why is Lord Vishnu blue in color?

Tags: vishnu

Why is Lord Vishnu portrayed in **blue** color? Is there any incident in Hindu mythology explaining this? If yes, then please do share that story!

Comment: I don't really know why my skin color is like the one i have.

Comment: I like the answer , which Brahmakumaris give for this . The gods became black because after many births they fall into vices and became ugly.Then Shiv , the Only true God who is also called The Purifier comes to make them beautiful once again.Humans in their purest form are deities. This probably is why the snake which bites all other gods and turns them blue - black , is tamed and found hanging around Shiv's neck.Its all symbolic not true images.

Comment: Related [Why is Krishna portrayed to be blue?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/46/277)

Answer (score 9):

Adding to Pandya's Answer, Skanda Purana explains how Vaikunta became blue and gives a reason for His color.

The [chapter 9 Churning of Ocean in Skanda Purana](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/skanda-purana/vol-i/chapter-09/topic-2) says Halahal Poison made Vaikunta blue and Lord Vishnu to color of Taamala.

> - By that time, the great poison, Kaalakuta came there. After burning Brahma's world at the outset, it burned Vaikunta.
> - Vishnu who dwells in the cavity of the heart of everyone, was burned by the fire of Kaalakuta also with his attendants. **Immediately
>   he acquired the color of [Tamaala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamomum_tamala).**
> - **Vaikunta also became blue in color**. It was surrounded by all the worlds. Hence all the worlds became encircled by the poisonous
>   substance from the waters.

Tamaala is Indian bay leaf. I checked [Sanskrit Verses](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/skanda-mahapuranam/vol-i/chapter-09/topic-1) and word **Taamala** is used to describe Vishnu. Bay leaves are generally [olive green in color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamomum_tamala#Characteristics) but dried leaves are brown in color. So, i'm not sure about what exactly does author mean by  color of Tamaala.

Comment: If Halahal poison made Vishnu blue (same as it made neck of Shiva blue) then do you know what was the color of Vishnu before effect of poison?

Answer (score 0):

> Vishnu's blue body is often depicted in blue. The color blue
>   symbolizes the infinite. Vishnu wears yellow clothing. The yellow
>   color is associated with the terrestrial life.
>
> [Source](http://1stholistic.com/Prayer/Hindu/hol_Hindu-vishnu.htm)

Color of lord Vishnu is yellow. That is why he is called as pitambar.